# SQL Server 2008 returns “Memory limit of 10240 KB exceeded for buffered query” in php

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv

I am trying to to get data from SQL server database and save to MySQL database using by `php_sqlsrv`. it works fine, but when I try to retrieve more than 1500 or more rows in one query it  shows this message:

> Error Number: IMSSP/-59 Memory limit of 10240 KB exceeded for buffered
>   query SELECT * FROM mytable;

How can I fix this? can we fix from php xammp? or is it a sqlsrv problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to adding `sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize = 10240` into your `php.ini`